# How do I reliably include multiple directories from external storage in Android backup rules on API ≤ 30?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have backup rules for API ≤ 30 like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="." />
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="encrypted_shared_preferences.xml" />
    <include domain="external" path="themes" />
    <include domain="external" path="fonts" />
</full-backup-content>
```

While similar rules work without issues for API > 30, on emulators with API versions 24 and 27 (at least) only one of these folders is restored.

Judging from the logcat messages, I can see that the files are backed up correctly, but when I look at the restored files, some folders are missing. I ran some more tests, and I see the following.
Here, on the left there are source folders, each with a file, and the according rules, and on the right the outcomes.

| Source | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| ahoy fonts fonts2 themes | ahoy |
| fonts fonts2 themes sausage | sausage |
| fonts fonts2 themes sausage sausage2 | sausage2 |
| amazing fonts fonts2 themes | fonts fonts2 |

I know that there's a limit on how much you can backup, but all of the files here have the size of 0, so it must be something else.

Is there a way around this?